# How to unchecked all actions on an action group menu on Qt?

Tags: qt, menu, qactiongroup

I have a method to automatically add checkable actions on a menu and it's working perfectly. I just like to know how to unchecked all these actions automatically. I know that it's possible with `ui->action_item->setChecked(false)` but in this case I should know and write each action name in the code however it's not viable for me.

Pseudo-code:

```
void MainWindow::AddNewActions() {
    QActionGroup *my_action_group = new QActionGroup(this);
    my_action_group->setExclusive(true);

    foreach (..) {
        QAction *my_new_action = new QAction(description, my_action_group);
        my_new_action->setCheckable(true);
        my_new_action->setData(action_name);

        ui_->my_menu->addAction(my_new_action);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is `ui->action_item`? you can give more detail in addition to providing a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

You need to get a list of actions, and then uncheck each of them. The list of actions is simply the list of `QAction` children of the menu - but that's if they don't belong to an action group. That would be, then:

```
void Class::method2() {
  auto actions = std::as_const(ui_->my_menu->findChildren<QAction*>());
  for (auto *action : actions)
    action->setChecked(false);
}
```

If you want to find actions in a particular action group, you need to name the action group with a unique name, to refer to it later:

```
static const QString k_my_action_group{QLatin1String("my_action_group")};

void Class::method1() {
  auto *my_action_group = new QActionGroup{this};
  my_action_group->setObjectName(k_my_action_group);
  ...
}

void Class::method2() {
  if (auto *group = findChild<QActionGroup*>(k_my_action_group))
    if (auto *action = group->checkedAction())
      action->setChecked(false);
}
```

If you have multiple groups, they can share the same name, and then you'd iterate them too:

```
void Class::method2() { // if somehow more than one action can be checked
  auto groups = std::as_const(findChildren<QActionGroup*>(k_my_action_group));
  for (auto *group : groups)
    if (auto *action = group->checkedAction())
      action->setChecked(false);
}
```

If your compiler doesn't implement `std::as_const` yet, use `qAsConst` instead. The const-casting is the unfortunate effect of the implicit shared design of Qt containers.

Object names referred to in multiple places should be used as string constants with symbolic names. This makes typos detectable at compile time, vs. at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

I implemented a simplest solution:

```
    QList<QMenu*> menus;
menus = ui->menuBar->findChildren<QMenu*>();

foreach (QMenu* menu, menus)
{
    foreach (QAction* action, menu->actions())
    {
        if(action->isCheckable()){
        action->setChecked(false);
        }
    }
}
```